# What is the purpose of using routes in $http requests

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

### **student.service.js**

```js
'use strict';

angular.module('StudentApp').factory('StudentService', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    return {
      get: () => $http.get('/students').then(response => response.data),
      add: student => $http.post('/students', student).then(response => response.data),
      delete: id => $http.delete('/students/' + id).then(response => response.data),
      //getById: id => $http.get('/students/' + id).then(response => response.data),
      update: (id, student) => $http.put('/students/' + id, student).then(response => response.data),
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: Please explain your question

Comment: Possibly you are referring to the ES6 fat arrow functions. See [MDN JavaScript Reference - Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean what is the path inside

```
$http.get('/students')
```

It is a relative path, and depending on what's the server-name where the app is running, it is translated like

```
https://yourdomain.com/students
```

( if you are running the app on `https://yourdomain.com` )

On the backend (API) the route will be translated to get the required result